# Pthreads and recursion

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm struggling with one of my training tasks for getting in touch with a new language. Unfortunately, this time the new language is an old one, it is C. My programming Task for this is to generate Langford-Strings, which should not be the main problem.

My first attempt in C, with a recursive approach works like a charm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int grade = 0;
const char* blank = "_";
const char* alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

void generate(int position, char* string) {

  if (!string) {
    string = calloc(grade*2+1, sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < grade*2; i++) {
      string = strcat(string, blank);
    }
  }

  if (!strstr(string, blank)) {
    printf("%s\n", string);
    return;
  }

  if (position < strlen(string)) {
    if (string[position] != *blank) {
      char* nstring = calloc(grade*2+1, sizeof(char));
      strcpy(nstring, string);
      generate(position+1, nstring);
      free(nstring);
      return;
    } else {
      for (int i = 0; i<strlen(string); i++) {
        if (strchr(string, alphabet[i])){
          continue;
        }

        int index = strcspn(alphabet, &alphabet[i])+1;
        if (position+index+1<strlen(string)) {
          if (string[position]==*blank) {
            if (string[position+index+1]==*blank) {
              char* nstring = calloc(grade*2+1, sizeof(char));
              strncat(nstring, string, position);
              strncat(nstring, &alphabet[i], 1);
              strncat(nstring, &string[position+1], index);
              strncat(nstring, &alphabet[i], 1);
              strcat(nstring, &string[position+2+index]);
              if (position<strlen(nstring)) {
                generate(position+1, nstring);
              }
              free(nstring);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Missing parameter of langford strings grade!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  grade = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  if (grade % 4 != 0) {
    if ((grade+1) % 4 != 0) {
      printf("Grade must be multiple of 4 or one less\n");
      return 1;
    }
  }

  generate(0, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

That works great, giving me exactly the results I expected.

But when I try to do it threaded (old-style threaded, spawning a new thread on each level of the recursion), it not only ends with a seqfault every time. It does end in an seqfault in a not predictable time. That means, that it runs indefinitly, printing out doubled and trippled results and always a random number of results, before seqfaulting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

size_t grade = 0;
const char* blank = "_";
const char* alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

struct thread {
  pthread_t* thread;
  size_t position;
  struct thread* threads[26];
  char* string;
};

void* alloc_thread_data() {
  struct thread* ret = calloc(1, sizeof(struct thread));
  ret->thread = calloc(1, sizeof(pthread_t));
  ret->position = 0;
  ret->string = calloc((grade*2)+1, sizeof(char));
  return (void*)ret;
}

void free_thread_data(struct thread* dst) {
  free(dst->string);
  free(dst->thread);
  free(dst);
}

void assemble_string(char* dst, char* src, size_t pos, size_t index) {
  strncat(dst, src, pos);
  strncat(dst, &alphabet[index-1], 1);
  strncat(dst, &src[pos+1], index);
  strncat(dst, &alphabet[index-1], 1);
  strncat(dst, &src[pos+2+index], (grade*2)-pos+index+2);
}

void* generate(void* data) {
  struct thread* args = (struct thread*)data;

  if (args->string && strlen(args->string)==0) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i<grade*2; i++) {
      strcat(args->string, blank);
    }
  }

  if (args->string && !strstr(args->string, blank)) {
    printf("%s\n", args->string);
    return NULL;
  }

  if (args->string && args->position<strlen(args->string)) {
    size_t sub = 0;
    if (args->string[args->position]!=*blank) {
      args->threads[sub] = alloc_thread_data();
      strcpy(args->threads[sub]->string, args->string);
      args->threads[sub]->position = args->position+1;
      pthread_create(args->threads[sub]->thread, NULL, generate, (void*)args->threads[sub]);
      sub++;
    } else {
      for (size_t i = 0; i<grade*2; i++) {
        if (strchr(args->string, alphabet[i])){
          continue;
        }

        int index = strcspn(alphabet, &alphabet[i])+1;
        if (args->string[args->position] == *blank) {
          if (args->string[args->position+index+1] == *blank) {
            args->threads[sub] = alloc_thread_data();
            assemble_string(args->threads[sub]->string, args->string, args->position, index);
            args->threads[sub]->position = args->position+1;
            pthread_create(args->threads[sub]->thread, NULL, generate, (void*)args->threads[sub]);
            sub++;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i<sub; i++) {
      if (args->threads[i]->thread!=NULL) {
        if(pthread_kill(*args->threads[i]->thread, 0)==0) {
          pthread_join(*args->threads[i]->thread, NULL);
        }

        free_thread_data(args->threads[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    printf("Missing parameter of langford strings grade!\n");
    return 1;
  }

  grade = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
  if (grade % 4 != 0) {
    if ((grade+1) % 4 != 0) {
      printf("Grade must be multiple of 4 or one less\n");
      return 2;
    }
  }

  struct thread* args = alloc_thread_data();
  pthread_create(args->thread, NULL, generate, (void*)args);
  if(pthread_kill(*args->thread, 0)==0) {
    pthread_join(*args->thread, NULL);
  }

  free_thread_data(args);
}
```

So, as written before, I managed to get around C programming for my whole work-life and do this just for fun - so I do not expect my code to be somewhat comprehensive. Please help me finding out, what is wrong with the threaded approach (and if you see any well-known-codesmell in the first one as well of course). Any hints welcome.

Comment: `ret->thread = calloc(1, sizeof(pthread_t*))` => `ret->thread = calloc(1, sizeof(pthread_t))`

Comment: thx, @EugeneSh. I fixed this, although it seems not to be the main hook.

Comment: You seem to be messing up memory. Consider running the code using a memory manager like Valgrind (https://valgrind.org).

Comment: About the update: It *is* useful. Look at the lines stated as invalid operation. they tell you exactly where you accessing memory you should not.

Comment: I am not sure why you are calling `pthread_kill` - You don't know whether it's finished already... And if it's not finished yet, there might be any kind of garbage in its data structure

Comment: @tofro sending pthread_kill with signal 0 to a thread would return an error !=0 if the thread is not running. Basically this is a check to see if the thread is running, before I try to join it, what would fail otherwise.

Comment: "*this is a check to see if the thread is running, before I try to join it,*" why do you do this? What makes you think the thread is gone? Attached threads "zombie" around until joined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the bad allocation that @EugeneSh. pointed out, this looks like a problem:

```
pthread_create(args->threads[sub]->thread, NULL, generate,
        (void*)&args->threads[sub]);
```

Note the difference from this other call that also appears:

```
pthread_create(args->threads[sub]->thread, NULL, generate,
        (void*)args->threads[sub]);
```

[newlines inserted and indentation normalized for clarity and ease of reading].

`args->threads[sub]` is a `struct thread*`.  You want to pass that pointer itself to `pthread_create()`, as in the second case, not its address, as in the first case.

Overall, I'm inclined to agree with @MikeRobinson that yours is an inappropriate use of threads.  It is never useful performance-wise to have more schedulable threads in your process than you have cores, and you scale up to many thousands of total threads very quickly.  I doubt very much that the result will outperform your single-threaded solution -- the costs of the context switching and cache thrashing that surely result will likely swamp whatever speedup you get from parallel execution on the 4 - 12 cores you probably have.

### Added:

Additionally, it is very important to check the values returned by your function calls for error codes, unless you don't care and don't need to care whether the calls succeed.  In particular, you should check

- the return values of your `malloc()` / `calloc()` calls -- these return `NULL` in the event of unsuccessful allocation, and with as many total allocations as you perform, it is plausible that some of these fail.  Using the resulting `NULL` pointer could easily lead to a segfault
- the return values of your `pthread_create()` calls -- these return a value different from 0 in the event of failure.  It is not safe to afterward rely on `pthread_kill()` to determine whether the thread was created successfully, for a failed `pthread_create()` leaves the thread handle's contents *undefined*.  Any subsequent evaluation that depends on the value of the handle therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

I'm also a little suspicious of all your `strncat()`ing, for this is a notorious source of string overruns.  These are ok if the target strings have enough capacity, but it's difficult for me to tell whether they always do in your case.

Comment: Thank you for your sight. As I stated before, this is merely a "can do" than a useful approach. Nevertheless, this does not solve the seqfault-problem. Although it seems to be seqfaulting less for grades less than 8.

Comment: @OliverFriedrich, I don't see another smoking gun, but I added some commentary about some additional weaknesses in your code.  The valgrind output you presented tells you exactly where the invalid accesses are occurring, which should help, but they don't tell *us* much because we can't match the line numbers to the code you presented.

Comment: pthread_create returned EAGAIN after constantly 11520 threads are active. With a stack size of 16384b (set by pthread_attr_setstacksize and PTHREAD_STACK_MIN) gives 180MiB of stack memory at where the program will stop working. At least I can confirm, nothing wrong with memory alloction and strncat ing. More information following.

Comment: @OliverFriedrich: So far about checking the outcome of relevant function calls ... ;-)

Answer (score -1):

May I cordially suggest that *it makes absolutely no **sense*** (to me, at least ...) to "spawn a new thread" here?

The **only** reason to "spawn a thread" is when you wish to perform two *thereafter, **independent*** activities, which this algorithm quite clearly does not.

The immediate reason for the segfault is that the various threads are all attempting to manipulate the same data without regard to one another, and without waiting for one another. But, IMHO, the root cause of the problem is ... that this entire scenario is *nonsense.* "Recursion" and "multi-threading" are not at all the same thing. If your objective here was to learn about threading, I'm afraid that you've just learned far more *(the very-hard way)* than you ever wished to know . . .

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely true. It is by far not the best approach for using threads to speed up the calculation (nor a sane one, because of heavily spawning threads). But why am I manipulating the same data?